# How do we ensure that HoloViews heatmaps have individual color scales?

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, holoviews

If I have a list of heatmaps:

```
[:HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value)]
```

and I plot them together:

```
hv.Layout(heatmaps).cols(1)
```

How do I ensure that they have individual color scales? I'm asking because the final scale for them seems to be synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, HoloViews assumes that if you lay things out together, you are doing so because you want to compare them to each other, so it makes sure all the axes that show the same dimensions are linked, making all the scales comparable.

You can override that assumption if you want each axis in each plot in the layout to be constructed separately, by enabling per-axis normalization with `.opts(axiswise=True)` on the layout.

Similarly, if you have multiple frames in a HoloMap, they will be normalized together by default to show changes in magnitude across them, but you can enable per-frame normalization with `.opts(framewise=True)`.